# KVM high CPU load

Tags: windows-server-2008, debian, kvm-virtualization

I have a dedicated machine running under Debian Squeeze. It's a reasonably good machine with 8 cores.

I started hosting a Windows Server 2008 guest with KVM, but the CPU load is extremely high (around 100%-200%) even when the guest is idle. What could explain such a behavior? Has anyone encountered it before? Does it come from KVM or Windows?

The Windows guest is up-to-date.

`> kvm -version :  emulator version 0.12.5 (qemu-kvm-0.12.5), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard`

I don't know what more details to provide, but please ask for more information if you need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the current qemu-kvm verison stands at 0.14
2. Without guest configuration details there is no way to know what's going on, and provide advice.
3. to troubleshoot kvm performance there is a tool called kvm_stat - it can show where the bottleneck is, if any
4. you might be seeing the qemu process going to 200% in `top` on the host, but do you really feel a performance hit on the host? Normally, when you assign more than one CPU to a VM, you might see the QEMU process showing high percentages, but that's only because `top` shows stats for a single CPU, and qemu-kvm is actually running several threads

Comment: Upgrading to 0.14 solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 2):

i experience with this problem last time (centos 5.4 64bit), i plan using kvm to replace xen, but we revert back to xen. i suspect the storage, but even using the local hdd, and KVM Paravirtualized drivers, kvm still got problem with high cpu load (may because of the kvm as kernel module, i don't know). i use for windows and linux.

Comment: KVM is under very heavy development, and has been updated many times since 5.4. try it on 5.7 or 6.1 - you'll see the difference